# local variable 'content' referenced before assignment django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to do a view in which users can respond by commenting or replying to a chapter by answering a form but I keep getting the local variable 'content' referenced before assignment error and I don't know why.
When I removed the content field the same happened to the parent field.

```
class ChapterView(DetailView):
    model = Chapter
    template_name = 'mangas/chapter.html'
    slug_field = 'chapter_slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'chapter_slug'

    def get_context_data(self , **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)    
        comments = ChapterComment.objects.filter(chapter=self.get_object())
        comments_number = comments.count()
        data['comments'] = comments
        data['comments_number'] = comments_number
        data['comment_form'] = CommentForm()
        return data

    def post(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST)
            comments = ChapterComment.objects.filter(chapter=self.get_object())
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                content = comment_form.cleaned_data['content']
                for comment in comments:
                    if comment.content == content:
                        messages.info(request, 'The comment is duplicate.')
                        return redirect(self.request.path_info)
                try:
                    parent = comment_form.cleaned_data['parent']
                except:
                    parent = None
            new_comment = ChapterComment(content=content, author=self.request.user , chapter=self.get_object(), parent=parent)
            new_comment.save()
            return redirect(self.request.path_info)
```

```
class ChapterComment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=550)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='replies')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'chapter-comment'
        verbose_name_plural = 'chapter-comments'
        ordering=['-date_posted']

    @property
    def children(self):
        return ChapterComment.objects.filter(parent=self).reverse()

    @property
    def is_parent(self):
        if self.parent is None:
            return True
        return False

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('chapter', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username + ' commented ' + self.content[:50]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_comment = ChapterComment(content=content, author=self.request.user , chapter=self.get_object(), parent=parent)
```

Here you are trying to use content, but if your form is invalid

```
if comment_form.is_valid():
     content = comment_form.cleaned_data['content']
```

content does not get assigned a value yet. Same is true for `parent`

```
 new_comment = ChapterComment(content=content, author=self.request.user , chapter=self.get_object(), parent=parent)
 new_comment.save()
```

This code has to be at the same identiation as `except`

And if the form is not valid you wouldnt want to create a new comment